# Spring cron job not working

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, cron

I am newbie with Spring framework. At the moment I try to integrate cron job service.

I defined a service class as:

```
package com.test.cron;
@Service
public class CronJob {
    protected static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(PasswordRemindFlusher.class);

    @Scheduled(cron="0 0/2 * * * ?")
    public void demoServiceMethod()
    {

        logger.debug("Cron job started.");
    }
}
```

Then I defined in servlet config:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.test.cron" />
```

spring-servlet.xml:

```
<?xml  version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/task 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task-3.0.xsd">

<context:annotation-config />

<context:component-scan base-package="com.test.cron" />
<task:annotation-driven />
</beans>
```

web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    version="2.5">
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring-servlet.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet> 
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Exception:

```
SEVERE: Exception sending context destroyed event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
java.lang.IllegalStateException: BeanFactory not initialized or already closed - call 'refresh' before accessing beans via the ApplicationContext
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.getBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:172)
```

All other controllers in the same package works.
I use Spring 3.1.2 framework. May I missed something?

Comment: Could you please post the complete xml configuration file, because Amudhan and Dave Syer are rigth, you need to add `<task:annotation-driven />`. On the other hand you wrote (in Amudhan's comment) that this lead to an exception. So something must be very wrong with your xml file, therefore please post the COMPLETE xml file, including the "header".

Comment: You appear to be loading the same XML file twice. Once should do (if you remove the ContextLoaderListener).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to add few things in your xml namespace and schema location. See [this](http://howtodoinjava.com/2013/04/23/4-ways-to-schedule-tasks-in-spring-3-scheduled-example/) guide.

Comment: If I try to add: <task:annotation-driven /> , I receive an exception, because in XML is written <context:annotation-config /> . If I delete <task:annotation-drive />, I don't receive error.

Answer (score 5):

Did you `@EnableScheduling` (or the Xml equivalent)? See [this guide](http://spring.io/guides/gs/scheduling-tasks/) for more detail.

Comment: If I try to add: <task:annotation-driven /> , I receive an exception, because in XML is written <context:annotation-config /> . If I delete <task:annotation-drive />, I don't receive error.

Comment: That doesn't make much sense. Can you show the exception. BTW, there's no need to reply the same way to more than one answer (even if they are the same) - we can all read all the comments.